# ListFragment Replace "addView(View) is not supported in AdapterView" after switching from SupportFragmentManager to FragmentManager

Tags: android, android-listview, android-fragments, android-listfragment, android-fragmentactivity

I have an activity which has a fragment. When I click on a list item the current fragment gets replaced with another fragment. This used to work correctly...

However, I would like to move away from SupportFragmentManager to FragmentManager...I will no longer support old android versions.

When I made the switch my app started crashing with the above error. Here is a full stacktrace...

```
05-06 05:24:35.868: E/AndroidRuntime(1381): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-06 05:24:35.868: E/AndroidRuntime(1381): java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: addView(View) is not supported in AdapterView
05-06 05:24:35.868: E/AndroidRuntime(1381):     at android.widget.AdapterView.addView(AdapterView.java:445)
05-06 05:24:35.868: E/AndroidRuntime(1381):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:839)
05-06 05:24:35.868: E/AndroidRuntime(1381):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1032)
05-06 05:24:35.868: E/AndroidRuntime(1381):     at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:622)
05-06 05:24:35.868: E/AndroidRuntime(1381):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1382)
05-06 05:24:35.868: E/AndroidRuntime(1381):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:426)
05-06 05:24:35.868: E/AndroidRuntime(1381):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
05-06 05:24:35.868: E/AndroidRuntime(1381):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
05-06 05:24:35.868: E/AndroidRuntime(1381):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-06 05:24:35.868: E/AndroidRuntime(1381):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
05-06 05:24:35.868: E/AndroidRuntime(1381):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-06 05:24:35.868: E/AndroidRuntime(1381):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-06 05:24:35.868: E/AndroidRuntime(1381):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
05-06 05:24:35.868: E/AndroidRuntime(1381):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
05-06 05:24:35.868: E/AndroidRuntime(1381):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

This is the only change that I made and now I am really confused.

Here are they key snippets of code:

Activity:

```
Fragment2 mFragment2 = new Fragment2();
FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
transaction.replace(R.id.listFragment1, mFragment2 , FRAGMENT2_FRAGMENT_TAG);
transaction.addToBackStack(null);
transaction.commit();
```

Fragment2:

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View fragment2= inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_fragment2,
                container, false);

        return fragment2;
    }
```

XML:

Activity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/listActivity"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" 
    android:background="@drawable/lists_background"
    android:divider="@color/black">

   <TextView
        android:id="@+id/list_header_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>
   <fragment
        android:id="@+id/listFragment1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/list_header_text"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        class="com.test.Fragment1"
        android:tag="Fragment1" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Fragment2:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"
        android:background="@drawable/lists_background"
        android:divider="@color/black"
        android:dividerHeight="1dip"
        android:clickable="true">
</ListView>
```

Thank you for your help and let me know if you need more info or details.

Comment: Don't replace fragments placed in the xml layouts. Use a container instead and programatically add them to that container.

Comment: Suggestion by @Luksprog helped solve the first problem. By creating a container I was able to replace the first fragment with the second. However, I am now getting the same error when I hit the back button and return FragmentA from backstack. Any suggestions?

Comment: Just for curiosity, can you wrap the `ListView` in another layout(a `FrameLayout`, `RelativeLayout` etc) and see how it goes?

Comment: Wow great that fixed it! Thank you @Luksprog. If you write an answer Ill give you the solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fragments that are going to be used in transactions shouldn't be placed in the xml layout. Instead a container layout should be used with the fragments being added to that container.

To avoid the `addView()` exception wrap your `ListView` in another layout, I don't know exactly why this happens but it seems the framework calls the `addView()`(which is not implemented for children of `AdapterView`) method when the fragments it's being rebuilt.

Comment: I am not very sure about it but after reading this answer I played a little bit with the xml and removed this line xmlns:tools=http://schemas.android.com/tools from my main container (android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout) and after that it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

The stack trace is telling you there's an error with an [AdapterView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html). Looking at the known subclasses, the only thing I see from your post that's an AdapterView is your ListView. Make sure you aren't trying to call addView(View) on that.

Comment: I am not calling addView anywhere... please take a look at the comment I made in response to @Luksprog above.

Answer (score 0):

Just to be clear, I also had the same problem that get me stucked for hours...

I had a Listview instead a LinearLayout, and gets me a lot of trouble,

Once I replaced for LinearLayout everything was fine